# Failed to set trace monitor for X. Variable X not found

Tags: r, bayesian, jags

I'm trying to implement a Bayesian model for football score prediction (English Premier League). I assume the number of scores follows the Poisson distribution with parameter lambda and this is the general formula:

> log(home_lambda) = mu + hfa + home_attack - away_def
>
> log(away_lambda) = mu + away_attack - home_def

where mu and hfa are the intercept and home field advantage respectively. And this is my data (380 x 8)
[image]

So basically I have 380x2 equations and 42 parameters (mu, hfa, attack ability of 20 teams and defence ability of 20 teams). Take the first match as an example:

```
FTHG[1] ~ dpois(home_lambda[1]) # FTHG is full time home goal
log(home_lambda[1]) = mu + hfa + att_Crystal_Palace - att_Arsenal

FTAG[1] ~ dpois(lam_a[1]) # FTAG is full time away goal
log(away_lambda[1]) = mu + att_Arsenal - def_Crystal_Palace
```

Below is my entire code

```
bayes_mod_string = " model{
  
  for (i in 1:380){
  
    FTHG[i] ~ dpois(lam_h[i])
    log(lam_h[i]) = mu + hfa + h_att[i] - a_def[i]
    FTAG[i] ~ dpois(lam_a[i])
    log(lam_a[i]) = mu + a_att[i] - h_def[i]
    
    h_att[i] ~ dnorm(0, 1/1e6) # the attack and defence ability of each team follows a Normal distribution
    a_def[i] ~ dnorm(0, 1/1e6)
    a_att[i] ~ dnorm(0, 1/1e6)
    h_def[i] ~ dnorm(0, 1/1e6)

  }
  
  mu ~ dnorm(0, 1/1e6)
  hfa ~ dnorm(0, 1/1e6)
  
}"

data_jags = as.list(test_set)

params = c('mu', 'hfa', unique(test_set$h_att), unique(test_set$a_def)) # 42 in total

bayes_mod_string = jags.model(textConnection(bayes_mod_string), 
                              data = data_jags, n.chains = 3)
update(bayes_mod_string, 1e3)

bayes_mod_sim = coda.samples(model = bayes_mod_string,
                             variable.names = params, n.iter = 1e3)
bayes_mod_csim = as.mcmc(do.call(rbind, bayes_mod_sim))
```

The error message is

> Warning: Failed to set trace monitor for att_Crystal_Palace
> Variable att_Crystal_Palace not found

Not only with the "att_Crystal_Palace" parameter but also with all parameters.

I tried typing out each team attack and defence ability separately, putting them in and out the for loop

```
att_Crystal_Palace  ~ dnorm(0, 1/1e6)
  att_Fulham  ~ dnorm(0, 1/1e6)
  att_Bournemouth  ~ dnorm(0, 1/1e6)
  att_Leeds  ~ dnorm(0, 1/1e6)
  att_Newcastle  ~ dnorm(0, 1/1e6)
  att_Tottenham  ~ dnorm(0, 1/1e6)
  att_Everton  ~ dnorm(0, 1/1e6)
  att_Leicester  ~ dnorm(0, 1/1e6)  
  att_Man_United  ~ dnorm(0, 1/1e6)
  att_West_Ham  ~ dnorm(0, 1/1e6)
  att_Aston_Villa  ~ dnorm(0, 1/1e6)
  att_Arsenal  ~ dnorm(0, 1/1e6)
  att_Brighton  ~ dnorm(0, 1/1e6)
  att_Man_City  ~ dnorm(0, 1/1e6)
  att_Southampton  ~ dnorm(0, 1/1e6)
  att_Wolves  ~ dnorm(0, 1/1e6)
  att_Brentford  ~ dnorm(0, 1/1e6)
  att_Nottm_Forest  ~ dnorm(0, 1/1e6)
  att_Chelsea  ~ dnorm(0, 1/1e6)
  att_Liverpool ~ dnorm(0, 1/1e6)
  
  def_Crystal_Palace  ~ dnorm(0, 1/1e6)
  def_Fulham  ~ dnorm(0, 1/1e6)
  def_Bournemouth  ~ dnorm(0, 1/1e6)
  def_Leeds  ~ dnorm(0, 1/1e6)
  def_Newcastle  ~ dnorm(0, 1/1e6)
  def_Tottenham  ~ dnorm(0, 1/1e6)
  def_Everton  ~ dnorm(0, 1/1e6)
  def_Leicester  ~ dnorm(0, 1/1e6)  
  def_Man_United  ~ dnorm(0, 1/1e6)
  def_West_Ham  ~ dnorm(0, 1/1e6)
  def_Aston_Villa  ~ dnorm(0, 1/1e6)
  def_Arsenal  ~ dnorm(0, 1/1e6)
  def_Brighton  ~ dnorm(0, 1/1e6)
  def_Man_City  ~ dnorm(0, 1/1e6)
  def_Southampton  ~ dnorm(0, 1/1e6)
  def_Wolves  ~ dnorm(0, 1/1e6)
  def_Brentford  ~ dnorm(0, 1/1e6)
  def_Nottm_Forest  ~ dnorm(0, 1/1e6)
  def_Chelsea  ~ dnorm(0, 1/1e6)
  def_Liverpool ~ dnorm(0, 1/1e6)
```

This time the error is

> RUNTIME ERROR:
> Compilation error on line 50.
> Attempt to redefine node def_Liverpool[1]

What the problem actually is and how can I tackle it?
If you'd like to get the data, it's here https://www.football-data.co.uk/englandm.php, season 2022/2023

Comment: You need to define `att_XXX` and `def_XXX` variables in the model block of your JAGS code and fit the data in the data block.  See section 2.5 of the JAGS manual.  You will probably find it easier to switch to arrays rather than free-standing variables.  (And hence change your input data to use `1` instead of `att_Arsenal` etc.)  I will try to provide a more complete answer if I have the time later today.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could provide your input data as the output from `dput` rather than providing a link to a webpage with many, many possible datsets.  Which one are you using and how have you transformed it for your analysis?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still reading `dput` but I'm not sure how to use it. I use data from Premier League season 2022/2023, you directly download it from here https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/2223/E0.csv

Comment: By saying "define `att_XXX` and `def_XXX` variables in the model block", do you mean I need to write all them our instead of using a for loop?

Comment: With your formulation, yes.  With my formulation (see my - partial - answer below), no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your primary problem is here

```
log(lam_h[i]) = mu + hfa + h_att[i] - a_def[i]
```

`h_att[i]` resolves to, say, `att_Arsenal`, as you say, but you don't define a node (variable) called `att_Arsenal`.   You have similar problems for `h_def`, `a_att` and `a_def`.

The easiest way to deal with this number of predictor variables is to use arrays rather than stand-alone scalars.  I've used data from the 2023/24 season from the link you provided.  My input data looks like this:

```
df
# A tibble: 39 × 7
   Div   Date       Time  HomeTeam AwayTeam  FTHG  FTAG
   <chr> <chr>      <chr>    <int>    <int> <int> <int>
 1 E0    11/08/2023 20:00        6       13     0     3
 2 E0    12/08/2023 12:30        1       16     2     1
 3 E0    12/08/2023 15:00        3       19     1     1
 4 E0    12/08/2023 15:00        5       12     4     1
 5 E0    12/08/2023 15:00        9       10     0     1
 6 E0    12/08/2023 15:00       17        8     0     1
 7 E0    12/08/2023 17:30       15        2     5     1
 8 E0    13/08/2023 14:00        4       18     2     2
 9 E0    13/08/2023 16:30        7       11     1     1
10 E0    14/08/2023 20:00       14       20     1     0
# … with 29 more rows
```

where I have indexed both `HomeTeam` and `AwayTeam` alphabetically.  So, Arsenal are `1` and Wolves are `20`.

Then I can write my model string as

```
bayes_mod_string = " 
data {
  mu ~ dnorm(0, 1/1e6)
  hfa ~ dnorm(0, 1/1e6)
  for (j in 1:nTeams) {
    h_att[j] ~ dnorm(0, 1/1e6) 
    a_def[j] ~ dnorm(0, 1/1e6)
    a_att[j] ~ dnorm(0, 1/1e6)
    h_def[j] ~ dnorm(0, 1/1e6)
    log(lam_h[j]) = mu + hfa + h_att[j] - a_def[j]
    log(lam_a[j]) = mu + a_att[j] - h_def[j]
  }
}

model {
  for (i in 1:nMatches) {
    FTHG[i] ~ dpois(lam_h[home[i]])
    FTAG[i] ~ dpois(lam_a[away[i]])
  }
}
"
```

Note the double-indexing of `lam_a` and `lam_h` in the model block.

I update the model and obtain samples with

```
library(rjags)

bayes_model = jags.model(textConnection(bayes_mod_string), 
                              data = data_jags, n.chains = 3)
data_jags <- list(
  nTeams = 20,
  nMatches = nrow(df),
  FTHG = df$FTHG,
  FTAG = df$FTAG,
  home = df$HomeTeam,
  away = df$AwayTeam
)

update(bayes_model, 1e3)

samples <- jags.samples(
  model = bayes_model,
  variable.names = c('mu', 'hfa', paste0("h_att[", 1:20, "]"), paste0("a_def[", 1:20, "]")), 
  n.iter = 1e3
)
```

Note that I've changed `coda.samples` to `jags.samples`.

I omit printing `samples` because the output is rather long.

Personally, I prefer `runjags` to `rjags`.  You can use the model string directly rather than passing through a text connection or writing to a file, the model fitting code is more compact and I feel the output is both more compact and more informative.

```
library(runjags)

run.jags(
  bayes_mod_string, 
  data = data_jags,
  monitor = c('mu', 'hfa', paste0("h_att[", 1:20, "]"), paste0("a_def[", 1:20, "]"))
)
Compiling rjags model...
Calling the simulation using the rjags method...
Note: the model did not require adaptation
Burning in the model for 4000 iterations...
  |**************************************************| 100%
Running the model for 10000 iterations...
  |**************************************************| 100%
Simulation complete
Calculating summary statistics...
Note: The monitored variables 'mu', 'hfa', 'h_att[1]', 'h_att[2]', 'h_att[3]', 'h_att[4]', 'h_att[5]', 'h_att[6]', 'h_att[7]', 'h_att[8]', 'h_att[9]',
'h_att[10]', 'h_att[11]', 'h_att[12]', 'h_att[13]', 'h_att[14]', 'h_att[15]', 'h_att[16]', 'h_att[17]', 'h_att[18]', 'h_att[19]', 'h_att[20]', 'a_def[1]',
'a_def[2]', 'a_def[3]', 'a_def[4]', 'a_def[5]', 'a_def[6]', 'a_def[7]', 'a_def[8]', 'a_def[9]', 'a_def[10]', 'a_def[11]', 'a_def[12]', 'a_def[13]',
'a_def[14]', 'a_def[15]', 'a_def[16]', 'a_def[17]', 'a_def[18]', 'a_def[19]' and 'a_def[20]' appear to be non-stochastic; they will not be included in the
convergence diagnostic
Finished running the simulation

JAGS model summary statistics from 20000 samples (chains = 2; adapt+burnin = 5000):
                                                                         
          Lower95 Upper95    Mean SD Mode MCerr MC%ofSD SSeff Lag.10 psrf
mu         827.99  827.99  827.99  0   --    --      --    --     --   --
hfa        1122.6  1122.6  1122.6  0   --    --      --    --     --   --
h_att[1]   287.62  287.62  287.62  0   --    --      --    --     --   --
h_att[2]  -696.89 -696.89 -696.89  0   --    --      --    --     --   --
h_att[3]   332.89  332.89  332.89  0   --    --      --    --     --   --
h_att[4]   941.39  941.39  941.39  0   --    --      --    --     --   --
h_att[5]   795.37  795.37  795.37  0   --    --      --    --     --   --
<further output omitted>
```

**IMPORTANT** The lack of variability in the output indicates a problem with either the model specification or my implementation.  Personally, I'd have fitted a hierarchical model.  I don't have time to explore further right now, but at least I've given you clues about how to proceed.

Comment: Thanks @Limeys ! It took me a while to modify. Actually I only know `coda.samples` and then I can plot the chains, gelman diagnostic and auto correlation. Let me try if I can do that with `runjags`.

Comment: I have another question for you about the hierarchical model, you mean to group the team and every team would have a different parameter lambda or this type (page 3 and 4)? https://discovery.ucl.ac.uk/id/eprint/16040/1/16040.pdf